# Why can't I create a string for transform:translate in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying this

```
$scope.graph.transform = "transform: translate(" + 
                          $scope.graph.width + "," + 
                          $scope.graph.height + ");";
```

All I get from

```
<h3>transform: <span ng-bind="graph.transform"/></h3>
```

is this

```
transform: transform: translate(undefined,undefined);
```

But I know the values are there, because if I do this

```
<h3>transform: <span ng-bind="graph.height"/></h3>
```

I get

```
transform: 336
```

**EDIT:**

This is also part of the code:

```
     $scope.graph = {};
     $scope.$watch(function(){
         return $window.innerWidth;
     }, function(value) {
         $scope.graph.width = value * 0.5;
     });

     $scope.$watch(function(){
         return $window.innerHeight;
     }, function(value) {
         $scope.graph.height = value * 0.5;
     });
```

Comment: I created a plunkr where it is working: http://plnkr.co/edit/VW9vr1FzI6iGHyUjQmGM. It must be a piece of your code that you are not showing that is breaking

Comment: @KevinF, maybe the code in the edit is the culprit? It breaks your plunkr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this:

```
$scope.graph = {};
```

you can default with

```
$scope.graph = {
    height: 0,
    width: 0
};
```

height and width are undefined until the watch triggers. And the way you are doing the watches is not checking for undefined. The first trigger of the watch is undefined and it might not trigger again until you resize the screen.

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ 
    return $window.innerWidth; 
}, function(value) {
    if(value){
        console.log(value);
    }
});

$scope.$watch(function(){ 
    return $window.innerHeight; 
}, function(value) {
    if(value){
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Also a $digest cycle is not triggered on window resize, only user events so you will need to do:

```
$window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(function(){
    $scope.$apply();
}, 500));
```

You'll want to debounce the event so that it doesn't get called every ms, it will crash your app, this is just using the [debounce function from here by David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function), but many libraries (like lodash, maybe jquery) already have one built in

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
}
```

Also binding the values the way you are doesn't get updated with the $watches. You can do:

```
<h3>transform: translate({{ graph.width }}, {{ graph.height }});</h3>
```

[Here is the updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VW9vr1FzI6iGHyUjQmGM), you have to resize the right window to get the $watch to trigger.

If you want to do a $watchGroup you can pass in an array of functions instead of just a single function

```
$scope.$watchGroup([function(){
    return $window.innerWidth;
}, function(){
    return $window.innerHeight;
}], function() {
    $scope.graph.width = $window.innerWidth / 2;
    $scope.graph.height = $window.innerHeight / 2;
});
```

[Here is a plunker demonstrating that](http://plnkr.co/edit/OqAebYYwIr6xy26G4yRq)

Comment: So yes, defining the values from start does fix it. But the watch is not working as it is, resizing the window has no effect.

Comment: This works, thanks. But I'm not succeeding in replacing `$scope.$watch` with `$scope.$watchGroup`, which seems a reasonable step. Would you be able to do it?